# Special characters problem when send data from react-native to laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, api, encode

I have a problem when i´m sending data from react-native to my laravel api, if i write something like this "araña" into a textInput and then catch that data into a state variable then send the data throw fetch api of javascript i get this into my database "ara\u00f1a", this is my code, i need to store that data "araña" and not "ara\u00f1a" i thought maybe it is a problem with the UTF-8 encode but i am not sure, how can i fix that?.

```
method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'charset': 'charset=UTF-8',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ result
          },
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to show where the problem is. Somewhere along your process your characters are converted into code points and it's probably not in the bit you've shared (or it's not clear if it is anyway).

Comment: @apokryfos sorry i already update the question, i´m note sure what else comment i just catch the data from textInput in my app and send it, when i get the data in laravel it show like this "ara\u00f1a" and i need this "araña" this character "ñ".